# Why the playlist chunk duration is different?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, ffprobe

I have this m3u8 playlist from Twitter/x which has this [chunk](https://prod-fastly-eu-west-1.video.pscp.tv/Transcoding/v1/hls/yVPxkkmoqa6Kfoq-TgCmX7mQjhTvMfic3HNNCRnLMP-YaRftEvt7k1QDIk9B9yDgrR7ibgkebVdkD_Ut5lH8Mw/non_transcode/eu-west-1/periscope-replay-direct-prod-eu-west-1-public/audio-space/chunk_1701372432609842942_707_a.aac):

```
#EXTINF:2.923,
chunk_1701372432609842942_707_a.aac
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2023-11-30T19:27:21.236Z
```

As you can see the duration of this chunk is `2.923`.

I tried to check the duration using ffprobe:

```
ffprobe chunk_1701372432609842942_707_a.aac 2>&1 | grep "Duration"
```

output:

```
Duration: 00:00:03.17, bitrate: 100 kb/s
```

I also tried to convert it to mp3, and it give me a different duration:

```
ffmpeg -i chunk_1701372432609842942_707_a.aac  -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 192k output.mp3
```

the duration of the mp3 file:

```
Duration: 00:00:02.95, start: 0.023021, bitrate: 197 kb/s
```

What is going on? which duration is the real one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bitrate: 100 kb/s` suggests to me that it is a variable bitrate encode.

There is one problem with variable bitrate encoding and that is that you have to 100% decode the entire file to get the true duration, as every block may have a different bitrate from the last. There might be headers at the front of the file describing how many blocks of data there are, but the amount of decoded audio data (and thus duration) of each block is somewhat arbitrary.

The result is that by decoding the first block in a variable bitrate file you can get a duration that does not reflect the true duration of the audio file.

According to [AAC stream in MP4 file has wrong duration. How to fix?](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/29555/41008) you can fully decode the file to get the "real" duration using `ffmpeg -i chunk_1701372432609842942_707_a.aac  -f null -`

MP3 has an additional issue that may or may not be shared by other formats.

From [How to Manually Fix Gapless Information in mp3 Files Using foobar2000 and Audacity](https://engagingdesign.wordpress.com/2019/09/29/how-to-manually-fix-gapless-information-in-mp3-files-using-foobar2000-and-audacity/):

> Mp3 is not an inherently gapless format–**the files have silent padding both at the beginning and the end of the file**. To get around this, metadata is embedded in the file to tell the mp3 player how long the padding is so it can skip playing the silence.

Also: [LAME Technical FAQ](https://lame.sourceforge.io/tech-FAQ.txt) (LAME is an MP3 encoder)

> **DECODER DELAY AT START OF FILE:**
>
> All *decoders* I have tested introduce a delay of 528 samples.  That
> is, after decoding an mp3 file, the output will have 528 samples of
> 0's appended to the front.  This is because the standard
> MDCT/filterbank routines used by the ISO have a 528 sample delay.  It
> would be possible to write a MDCT/filterbank routine with a 0 sample
> delay (see description of Takehiro's MDCT/filterbank routine used in
> LAME encoding below) but I dont know that anyone has done this.

And there is related padding at the end of a file as well.

Both of which can again affect the duration shown for a file.

I would trust the original M3U playlist file first, and then if in doubt check the actual audio data using a program which can decode the entire file such as Audacity.